# Two activities and null in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two activities: one is `actionbar` where I have some ImageViews, and a second class which is extended from the first one. In this second activity I want to change the icon of some Imagesviews from the first activity. This is possible.

When I try:

```
check_box_list_view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.email_list_item_checkbox_icon);
```

I get null. How I can get access in the second activity the ImageResoure image from the first activity?

ActionBarVCard:

```
public class ActionBarVCard extends Activity{
    private ImageView action_bar_home_icon, action_bar_title_icon, action_bar_vCard_icon;
    private TextView action_bar_title_text;
    private RelativeLayout relative;
    private ActionBar action;
    private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        action = getActionBar();
        relative = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
        action_bar_home_icon = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        action_bar_vCard_icon = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        action_bar_title_icon = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        action_bar_title_text = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

        action_bar_home_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.home_android);
        params.setMargins(20, 0, 20, 0);
        action_bar_home_icon.setLayoutParams(params);
        action_bar_home_icon.setId(1);
        action_bar_home_icon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ActionBarVCard.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("ClassName", "action_bar_coverView_icon");
                startActivity(intent);              
            }
        });

        params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, action_bar_home_icon.getId());
        params.setMargins(0, 10, 5, 0);
        action_bar_title_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.twoarrows_icon);
        action_bar_title_icon.setLayoutParams(params);
        action_bar_title_icon.setId(2);

        params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, action_bar_title_icon.getId());
        action_bar_title_text.setText("vCard");
        action_bar_title_text.setTextSize(24);
        action_bar_title_text.setLayoutParams(params);
        action_bar_title_text.setId(3);

        params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 20, 0);
        action_bar_vCard_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.installvcard_selected_android);
        action_bar_vCard_icon.setLayoutParams(params);
        action_bar_vCard_icon.setId(4);

        action.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        action.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        action.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        relative.addView(action_bar_home_icon);
        relative.addView(action_bar_title_icon);
        relative.addView(action_bar_title_text);
        relative.addView(action_bar_vCard_icon);
        relative.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        action.setCustomView(relative);

        return true;
    }
}
```

vCard:

```
public class vCard_view extends ActionBarVCard{
    Button speichernButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
         setTheme(R.style.mytheme);
         setContentView(R.layout.vcard_view);
         speichernButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speichern_button);
         speichernButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

and I would like to change icon for example action_bar_home_icon in vCard class but I don't know how

Comment: Please post your onCreate() methods for both activities and you can also post your screen layout xml so we can help you..